# Create nested conditions with drag and drop in JQuery / Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, tree, nested

I need to implement a form where there are multiple conditions (if this then that). These are nested conditions with drag and drop feature. Below is the design which explains concept - 
[image: an example of what I would like]

It would be helpful if you can share some references of plugins using which I can create this (Angular or JQuery). 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen [jQuery QueryBuilder](https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/)? This seems like exactly what you want.

Comment: perfect answer, this is what I wanted, thanks a lot!